# enable CORS in mendix

Tags: javascript, pdftron, mendix

I made an error when I integrated the pdftron widget for mendix (low code). I couldn't link external links when CORS block...Access to XMLHttpRequest at   been blocked by CORS policy : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide more details on where this is occurring?
Which network request is failing due to CORS?